# Building Qt6 application with poky (kirkstone)

Tags: bitbake, qt6, yocto-recipe, yocto-kirkstone

I am trying to build my custom recipe for [qeframework](https://github.com/qtepics/qeframework). I have setup by build system with poky (kirkstone) + meta-qt6 (6.4.3). During compilation bitbake is unable to find Makefile because qmake6 is not executed.

How I should be able to build custom Qt6 application through poky?

```
DESCRIPTION = "qeframework "
SUMMARY = "qeframework for epics"

DEPENDS = ""
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=e6a600fd5e1d9cbde2d983680233ad02"

SRCREV="73a31dd35cb53968a95725a26638e4294f99c663"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/qtepics/qeframework.git;branch=master;protocol=https"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS += "qtbase epics-base"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

B = "${S}/qeframeworkSup/project"

inherit qt6-qmake

PACKAGES = "${PN}"

do_configure[noexec] = "1"
```

I wrote this recipe and realised from the build log that qmake is never applied. Is there anything wrong in this recipe? Compile failed expectedly because pro file never created a Makefile.